# Frog Jump time complexity

Tags: c#, programming-challenge, complexity

I have tried to work out the Frog Jump task on Codility. The algorithm for solving this is rather simple but the maximum score I am able to achieve is 55% (also 44% with modulus operations).

> A small frog wants to get to the other side of the road. The frog is currently located at position X and wants to get to a position greater
>   than or equal to Y. The small frog always jumps a fixed distance, D.
>
> Count the minimal number of jumps that the small frog must perform to reach its target.
>
> Write a function: `class Solution { public int solution(int X, int Y, int D); }` that, given three integers X, Y and D, returns the minimal
>   number of jumps from position X to a position equal to or greater than
>   Y.

```
public static int solution(int X, int Y, int D)
{
    int count = 0;

    //55%
    if (X == Y)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        while (X < Y)
        {
            X += D;
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

I have read in a place that switch statements can outperform if conditions but couldn't find a way to make a switch statement out of this, also tried to get the answer recursively, but was only able to put down the base case..

Appreciate hints, help, suggestions at what should I look for to be optimal with this method.

Comment: Wouldn't this be `return (int)Math.Ceiling((float)(Y - X) / D);`?

Comment: It is.. I have definitely have to read thoroughly the Math class.. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad it helped. :)

Comment: @DerKommissar could you please explain in terms of time complexity why using Math.Ceiling is better in terms of if/else conditions? And also add your comment as an answers so I can mark it as such. Thanks again.

Comment: @Kris `Math.Ceiling` is `O(1)` as well as the expression passed to it. Your algorithm is `O(solution(X,Y,D)) = O(ceil((Y - X) / D))` because it is linearily dependent on the output value itself.